# TFS Build Workflow add a new test activity for Coded UI tests

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, build-automation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to create a build workflow for TFS that enables the following sequence of events (for now for a Web App, but in the future for Sharepoint projects to):

Build -> Test (Unit Tests) -> Deploy to IIS - Test (Coded UI) - Test (Load)

Up to the deploy I managed to configure the workflow, the problem start after. I'm having trouble the decide where to start. Is it better to create a new activity for each test using workflow components or go the powershell route?

One caveat, the virtualization infrastructure that exists is not MS so I cannot go the Lab Management route.

Thanks in advance for your insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in position to implement your test-invoking via Powershell, I think this would be your best way to proceed.
You would have to implement an "execute Powershell" part in your build script (see [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-14-Execute-a-PowerShell-script.aspx)) & maintain your *.ps1 in the source control.
For different/various projects you could construct a Build [Argument](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/27/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-2-Add-arguments-and-variables.aspx) that points to a user-inserted Path to the powershell-file that should execute in the given build definition. 
This Path could even be from source control. In this case you would have to enter `$/path/.../script.ps1` in the Proces of each Build Definition and have a `ConvertWorkspaceItem` execute before consuming it during Build.
Since you are not using MTM/Lab Management, I think this can be a nice/flexible alternative.

Comment: I'm trying this route now. Is there a way to see the test results (not just success / fail) of the build summary. With unit tests if they fail we can get to the test results directly in VS.

Comment: In order for your test results to be visible in the build summary, they have to get published into TFS as part of your build. I don't know how this can be done in the case of CodedUI, my (main) testrunner is NUnit & in this case there is this useful utility: http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/releases/view/45765. You need to search for (or implement) something similar (the general strategy is to convert the test results into TRX, then publish TRX during build).